# Tool in Toolbar is not visible in Customise Commans tab

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, syntaxerror

I have added a tool in a toolbar in python addin wizard. And while opening arcmap I am getting the error :---

> c:\arcgis\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Space Time Pattern Mining Tools.pyt
>
> ```
> ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

and tool is not visible in command tab of customize window. Please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please include a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck.  In this case I think that should be the `*.py` from the `install` subfolder and the `config.xml` of the addin project folder for a test project that has just the part that you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your code. Open your python code using an ide . In an ide you can debug and trace your error.

Pythonwin and  pyscripter are  ide's that you can use.see [how to debug python script](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/debugging-script-tools.htm)